# How to burn an MKV file with subtitles to DVD?

Tags: windows, conversion, dvd, dvd-burning, matroska

I have a DVD disc with an mkv file and the corresponding subtitles (.srt)
If I insert the DVD in a PC, all works ok.

But if I insert the DVD in a regular DVD player, I see `invalid disk`.

How should I convert/burn the file along with the subtitles in order to be able to use it in any DVD player?

Comment: Are you willing to spend money?

Comment: I'd rather not. Wait.You mean that this conversion is impossible without buying something?

Comment: No, but I'm not familiar with Windows tools to achieve this. I only know that there are commercial DVD authoring tools that definitely do this.

Comment: Do you perhaps know in Ubuntu?I may be able to get an Ubuntu PC if I can not do it in my Windows

Comment: [Plenty](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DVDAuthoring) to choose [from](http://linuxappfinder.com/multimedia/dvdauthoring) — although you have to check whether MKV and subtitles are supported. Basically the idea is to just "author" a DVD from the video file.